# Using Bootstrap Scrollspy in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, gatsby

I am trying to use [bootstrap scrollspy](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp) in Gatsby JS app.

So far inside my main container div I've added this (`index.js`):

```
 <div className="main-container" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
      <Layout>
      <Header />
</div>
```

And then for each section there is an id where this is suppose to add an `active` class whenever you scroll to it. But it did not work.

I also tried adding the following on my main class:

```
 <div className="main-container" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#nav-scroll-target" data-offset="0">
      <Layout>
      <Header />
</div>
```

And then inside my `<Navbar/>` component I've added an id so this can be targeted:

```
 <nav id="nav-scroll-target">
      
  </nav>
```

But this one also did not work. Any idea what's causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a structure like that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
      position: relative; 
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">  
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Section 4
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section41">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section42">Link 2</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="section1" class="container-fluid bg-success" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid bg-warning" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid bg-secondary" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section41" class="container-fluid bg-danger" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section42" class="container-fluid bg-info" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The key parts are the `data-target:".navbar"` of the scrollable element (`<body>` tag in this case) and the  that matches exactly the same class name (`<nav class="navbar ...">`). You need to adapt this structure to your snippet, changing your `<nav>` to:

```
 <nav id="nav-scroll-target" className="navbar">
      
  </nav>
```

Comment: Quick question though where do I put the attribute on body in gatsby? Is that inside the public/index.html?

Comment: Yes, natively you can access it there but there's a lot of options to customize the HTML output. In this case, it's in the `body` but you can adapt it to your needs.